# how can I use @RequestMapping or @GetMapping annotation without whitelabel error?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I used @RequestMapping or @GetMapping for routing. 
But, it doesn't work. It makes `whitelabel error page`.
(spring boot)

my Application.java

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class SmDemoApplication {

@RequestMapping("/")
String home() {
    return "Hello World! smDemo 111";
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SmDemoApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

And controller is

```
@RestController
public class WebRestController {

    //@GetMapping("/hello")
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World! 222";
    }

}
```

`http://localhost:8080` is good.
but, `http://localhost:8080/hello` makes white label error !!
what's the problem in my code?? (I made my project, using `spring starter project`)

Comment: what does the log say?? ..since "white label" means "server error"

Comment: `This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Jan 25 11:44:54 KST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available`

Comment: Show the packages structure and complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Springboot reads its stereotype beans ,controllers and configurations from package and subpackages of main class,(until you define @ComponentScan to read other packages) I feel your project main class is in another package than the controller i.e. Controller is not in same or in a sub package where Main class is.
For example , If your main package is in

```
com.xyz.abc
|_ SmDemoApplication
```

Keep controller,other beans and configuration in **com.xyz.abc package** like

```
com.xyz.abc
    |_WebRestController
```

**or sub-packages like**

```
com.xyz.abc.controllers
|_WebRestController
```

Comment: I didn't believe it at first. I didn't think it was just that kind of problem. However, I just tried and the problem was solved!!! woowwww!! thanks! XD. Then, is there any other way, not using sub package?

Comment: For not using subpackage use annotation @ComponentScan and in parameters add the packages to scan for.
For example @ComponentScan({"com.anotherpackage","com.onemorepackage"})
You can add exclude too.